# C interrupts on Cortex M3

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller, interrupt, cortex-m

I'm currently trying to implement interrupts on the STM32L152. I'm not using the standard peripheral libraries because I find them very confusing and difficult to get my head around. I'm not too competent with C for micro controllers yet.

I currently do everything through registers. Is there a way to implement interrupts in C through registers? There doesn't seem to be any information that actually makes sense out there. I did find learning C to be very inaccessible in the first place tbh.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "implement interrupts"? Do you mean "register a functor to the interrupt vector table"? Do you simply mean enabling/disabling them? Do you want to know how to use interrupts generated by I/O pins that can cause them? Do you just want to know how to bind to things like timers? We need more details of what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay sorry for the lack of clarification.

I want to wake the processor up from a low power state once a button is pressed. I don't know where to start. How do I do this? I completely understand the concepts of interrupts - just find the documentation on actually how to do it either assumes you already no how to do it or doesn't exist.

Comment: the problem you are encountering has less things to do with C language than CPU architecture. maybe you can start with CPU manual first.

Comment: I also don't understand how to use vector tables.

Comment: @GeorgeWaller You can't deal with interrupts without understanding the  underlying mechanism, which is the Interrupt controller, along with interrupt vectors. The same apply to everything else involved with hardware-software interaction. Start here for interrupts, but make sure go over other sections as well: http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/E-Book/C12_Interrupts.htm

Comment: What @EugeneSh. says - if you don't understand the hardware, you're shagged.  It's also true that, with embedded, even if you understand the hardware you can still be shagged for some time, even with a debugger, scope etc.

Comment: User manual, manufacturer's example code.  Over, and over, again, until you get something working.

Comment: Sounds like you need an external INT or GPIO interrupt.  There is a LOT to set up - PINSEL, interrupt-mask for GPIO port, mask of VIC, enable of VIC, load of vector table.  You HAVE to understand what is going on, or you will probably never get it to work.

Comment: Thanks. @MartinJames could you link to something suitable? I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: The STM32L152 data sheet says that an external line can be configured as a wake-up pin, without using interrupts, but I cannot find a code example. Section 10.2.3 in http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf

Comment: In case you are talking of the NVIC, you need to look for ARM documents (e.g. DUI0552), because the NVIC is part of the ARM Cortex-M3 core. Though for the core it is IMHO better to use CMSIS instead of the raw registers.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can implement interrupts by setting registers.

1. The registers-values tell the STM how to deal with interrupts, which interrupt is enabled, how the interrupt-controller has to work.
2. You'll need an Interrupt-vector-table. When an interrupt occurs a the program-counter will be set to an specific address of program-memory. There you should place a jump-command (assembler jmp) to your interrupt-service-routine.

You should read chapter 10 in [this reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf).

Hope this helps.